# Converting number to date with the year sometime first and sometimes last

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `dirty` dataset where a column contains a legitimate date with year first or year last or no date at all.

I am trying to convert this to a legitimate date, creating blanks for cells where it is not a real date

I have tried using `to_datetime`, but the `format='%Y%m%d'` will only work for the full frame. Adding `errors = "ignore"`, change none of the data.

Added the above to a "Try" statement does not work either.

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf['name'] = ('leon','eurika','monica','wian')
newdf['surname'] = ('swart','swart','swart','swart')
newdf['birthdate'] = ('14051981','19800911','1012','20100621')

newdf['birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(newdf['birthdate'], format='%Y%m%d')


     name surname  birthdate
0    leon   swart 1981-05-14
1    eurika   swart 1980-09-11
2    monica   swart  
3    wian   swart 2010-06-21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different format of `datetime`s, so possible solution is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` and [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(newdf['birthdate'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(newdf['birthdate'], format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')

newdf['birthdate'] = d1.fillna(d2)
print (newdf)
     name surname  birthdate
0    leon   swart 1981-05-14
1  eurika   swart 1980-09-11
2  monica   swart        NaT
3    wian   swart 2010-06-21
```